# Is it possible to delay setAnimationDidStopSelector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made a UIImageView, added it to the subview, and plan to animate it.  I am using the setAnimationDidStopSelector method and was wondering if I could get it to call a function 3 or so seconds after the animation stops.

Here is the current line of code I am using:

```
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(onAnimationComplete:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From your `animationDidStopSelector` method you can call another method using [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_).